# Comparing the same value, operator == cannot be used when vector3 is negative?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an NPC that chases the Player according to the path found in the pathfinding. Here when the position of the NPC is in the same coordinates as the path found, the NPC will change its speed. Here I have tried to use the == operator to compare the x or z positions in the coordinates whether they are equal. it can be done when the value of x or z is positive, but it is always FALSE when the value of x or z on the NPC and destination is negative. 
This is console position results after program ran:

FALSE

NPC position in Z coordinates: -2.3

NPC position in X coordinates: -0.5

PATH position in Z coordinates: -0.5

PATH position in X coordinates: -0.5

What I should want is when the NPC in the X coordinate and the PATH in the X coordinate are equal, no matter negative or positive.
What exactly should I do?

And this is the code that I use :

```
public virtual void UpdatePosition(Vector3 destination)
    {
        Node node = m_grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(transform.position);

        Vector3 direction = destination - transform.position; //destination is path found from pathfinding
        Vector3 PosNPC = transform.position - new Vector3(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f);

        if (true) 
       {
            //get position x and z of npc and path found
            //in this statment, if x or z of npc and path is same so npc will increase speed, if not npc will decrease speed
            if (PosNPC.z.ToString("f1") == destination.z.ToString("f1") || PosNPC.x.ToString("f1") == destination.x.ToString("f1")) 
            {

                movementSpeed = 2f;
                print("TRUE");
            }
            else if (PosNPC.z.ToString("f1") != destination.z.ToString("f1") || PosNPC.x.ToString("f1") != destination.x.ToString("f1"))
            {
                movementSpeed = 1f;
                print("FALSE");
            }
        }

        //Position NPC
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position NPC in koordinat Z : " + PosNPC.z.ToString("f1"));
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position NPC in koordinat X : " + transform.position.x.ToString("f1"));
        //Position PATH
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position PATH  in koordinat Z : " + destination.z.ToString("f1"));
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position PATH in koordinat X : " + destination.x.ToString("f1"));

        //move
        transform.Translate(direction.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Speed NPC : " + movementSpeed);

    }
```

Comment: You're printing out `transform.position` and comparing with `PosNPC.x`, which is offset by -0.1 on the X axis.

Comment: Why are you converting the floats before comparing them? Seems very inefficient.

Comment: @SimonC because he don't know  how to compare floats correctly ([and obviosuly x ==  y will not return what he wants in some cases](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZPAQGI))

Comment: @SimonC , because when I run with PosNPC.x then the results are (Position NPC in koordinat Z : -0.5844525) , while the PATH position is (-0,5).. so its not equal. what should I do ?

Comment: use rounding and proper floats comparsion (there are already question about both of that topics here on StackOverflow, so use search engine)

Comment: You asked the exact same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908145/why-cannot-compare-two-negative-values-is-equal-using-operator

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing the numbers correctly.
Don't convert them to a string beforehand, this will cause you lots of pain in the long run.

Instead, use the features the framework provides you with.
You want to round the number to a single digit (I'd do two, but that's just me) and then you can compare the numbers.

```
public virtual void UpdatePosition(Vector3 destination) {
    Node node = m_grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(transform.position);

    Vector3 direction = destination - transform.position; //destination is path found from pathfinding
    Vector3 posNPC = transform.position - new Vector3(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f);

    //get position x and z of npc and path found
    //in this statment, if x or z of npc and path is same so npc will increase speed, if not npc will decrease speed
    if (Math.Round(posNPC.z, 1) == Math.Round(destination.z, 1) || Math.Round(posNPC.x, 1) == Math.Round(destination.x, 1)) {

        movementSpeed = 2f;
        print("TRUE");
    } else if (Math.Round(posNPC.z != Math.Round(destination.z, 1) || Math.Round(posNPC.x, 1) != Math.Round(destination.x, 1))) {
        movementSpeed = 1f;
        print("FALSE");
    }

    //Position NPC
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position NPC in koordinat Z : " + posNPC.z.ToString("f1"));
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position NPC in koordinat X : " + transform.position.x.ToString("f1"));
    //Position PATH
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position PATH  in koordinat Z : " + destination.z.ToString("f1"));
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Position PATH in koordinat X : " + destination.x.ToString("f1"));

    //move
    transform.Translate(direction.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Speed NPC : " + movementSpeed);

}
```